# Are there statistics on how many people support or oppose vaccine mandates in the US by vaccination status?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, statistics, vaccine

Is there a fairly recent study showing how many people in the US support or oppose vaccine mandates broken down by vaccination status (how many vaccinated or unvaccinated people support or oppose mandates)?

Comment: From August 2021: https://news.gallup.com/poll/354506/update-american-public-opinion-vaccination-requirements.aspx KFF has a lot of relevant data from March 2022 but I didn't see this question addressed directly: https://www.kff.org/coronavirus-covid-19/dashboard/kff-covid-19-vaccine-monitor-dashboard/#vaccines